# Proving the convergence of the sequence $a_n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I encountered an interesting sequence $(a_n)$ defined by $a_n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x^n}$ where $x\in\mathbb R\setminus \{\pm1\}$. Based on my observations, I noticed that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $|x|<1$} \\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I am not sure where to start proving this result. I thought about applying this geometric series identity: $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ to get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n+x^{n+1}}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n}$$

But it looks complicated. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $|x| < 1$, then $1 - x^{n+1}, 1 - x^n \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$. If $|x| > 1$, then $1 - x^{n+1} \approx -x^{n+1}$ and $1 - x^n \approx -x^n$ for large $n$.

Comment: @anomaly Thanks, I know how to prove the result for $|x|<1$ case but I have difficulties with $|x|>1$ case. How can you justify the approximation $1-x^{n+1}\approx -x^{n+1}$ for large $n$?

Comment: Show that for fixed $|x| > 1$, we have $|x^{n+1}| = |x|^{n+1} \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: For $~x > 1,~$ rewrite $$a_n = 1 + \frac{x^n - x^{n+1}}{1 - x^n}.$$  As $~n \to \infty,~$ the denominator, $~1 - x^n~$ will *tend* towards $~-x^n,~$ while the numerator of the 2nd term equals $~x^n(1-x).$  The informal analysis in this comment should provide a guide to constructing a formal $~\epsilon ~: ~N~$ proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could proceed in the following way.

If $\,|x|<1\,,\,$ then $\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^n=0\,,\,$ consequently ,

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x^n}=\dfrac{1-0}{1-0}=1\,.$

If $\,|x|>1\,,\,$ then $\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{x^n}=0\,,\,$ consequently ,

$\require{cancel}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x^n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x^n\left(\frac1{x^n}-x\right)}{x^n\left(\frac1{x^n}-1\right)}=$
$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac1{x^n}-x}{\frac1{x^n}-1}=\dfrac{0-x}{0-1}=x\,.$